# Table row animation slides the row on top of the other row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am removing tableview rows using `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`

The mechanism works just fine.
My only problem is that visually when the cell is disappearing from the view, it is sliding on top of the cell above it, instead of behind it.

How can I make the cell go under the cell above it, instead of visually above it?

Here is my code:

```
    -(void)reloadTableRowsWithAnimation {
    NSMutableArray<NSIndexPath *> *selectedIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray<NSIndexPath *> alloc]init];

   [self.appsDataSource.selectedRows enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
       [selectedIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
    }];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:selectedIndexPaths
                          withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self reloadAppsBeforeReloadTableView];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: What is the iOS version you are running on? Can try with row animation option `UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle `.

Comment: I am compiling for iOS 8.4, I tried animation middle, the animation is more gentle to the eye, but still it is on top of the rows, instead of behind them

Comment: That most likely would be iOS bug as I see the row going nicely under the top row in iOS 9.